# How to find all Instants which correspond to the given LocalDateTime and ZoneId?

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, localtime, java.time.instant

When converting `Instant` to `LocalDateTime` it may happen that several different `Instant`s are converted into the same `LocalDateTime`. Eg. in time zones with day light saving time.

My question is whether it's possible to write a general function which works for any `ZoneId` and `LocalDateTime` and returns all `Instant`s which are in the given time zone mapped to the given `LocalDateTime`:

```java
List<Instant> localToInstants(LocalDateTime dt, ZoneId zone)
```

Comment: In practice there will always be at most two such `Instant`s. And there may be none at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ✔️

### Edit

M. Prokhorov’s idea of using `ZoneRules.getValidOffset()` gives more elegant code than I had in my original answer. Here’s a version that returns a list of `Instant`s as requested:

```
public static List<Instant> localToInstants(LocalDateTime dt, ZoneId zone) {
    return zone.getRules()
            .getValidOffsets(dt)
            .stream()
            .map(dt::atOffset)
            .map(OffsetDateTime::toInstant)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Let’s try it out on a couple of non-trivial examples. Malta will transition to summer time on March 28. At 2 AM the clocks are turned forward to 3. So the time 2:30 does not exist on this day. Which means that we expect an empty list from the following call:

```
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 28, 2, 30);
    System.out.println(localToInstants(dt, ZoneId.of("Europe/Malta")));
```

Output is indeed:

> []

This is Java’s way of printing an empty list. How it works: Since the time does not exist, `ZoneRules.getValidOffsets()` returns an empty list. The rest is boring: There are no offsets to convert to `OffsetDateTime` and further to `Instant`, so the empty list is returned.

My other example is from Eater Island. According to my Java 9 summer time will end on May 8. At 22 the clocks will be turned back to 21. So the time 21:30 occurs twice. Let’s see:

```
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.MAY, 8, 21, 30);
    System.out.println(localToInstants(dt, ZoneId.of("Pacific/Easter")));
```

> [2021-05-09T02:30:00Z, 2021-05-09T03:30:00Z]

Since the UTC offset changes from -05:00 to -06:00, the instants are correct. In this case `getValidOffsets()` returned two valid offsets, -05:00 and -06:00, so the code produced two `OffsetDateTime` objects which were in turn converted to two different `Instant` objects.

### Original answer

I am letting this stand in case anyone is interested in getting the appropriate `ZonedDateTime` objects.

```
public static List<Instant> localToInstants(LocalDateTime dt, ZoneId zone) {
    return Stream.of(dt.atZone(zone).withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap(),
                     dt.atZone(zone).withLaterOffsetAtOverlap())
            .filter(zdt -> zdt.toLocalDateTime().equals(dt))
            .map(ZonedDateTime::toInstant)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Let’s try it out on a couple of non-trivial examples. Malta will transition to summer time on March 28. At 2 AM the clocks are turned forward to 3. So the time 2:30 does not exist on this day. Which means that we expect an empty list from the following call:

```
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 28, 2, 30);
    System.out.println(localToInstants(dt, ZoneId.of("Europe/Malta")));
```

Output is indeed:

> []

This is Java’s way of printing an empty list. How it works: Since the time does not exist, `dt.atZone(zone)` gives us 3:30 instead of 2:30. Java adds the length of the gap, one hour as usual for a summer time transition. The calls to `withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap()` and `withLaterOffsetAtOverlap()` make no difference in this case (I will return to them), so we just get the same `ZonedDateTime` twice. The call to `filter()` is what makes the difference: we convert `ZonedDateTime` back to `LocalDateTime` and discover that we didn’t get the same time, therefore we discard the results. The rest is boring: there are no `ZonedDateTime`s to convert to `Instant`, so we end up with an empty list.

My other example is from Eater Island. According to my Java 9 summer time will end on May 8. At 22 the clocks will be turned back to 21. So the time 21:30 occurs twice. Let’s see:

```
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.MAY, 8, 21, 30);
    System.out.println(localToInstants(dt, ZoneId.of("Pacific/Easter")));
```

> [2021-05-09T02:30:00Z, 2021-05-09T03:30:00Z]

Since the UTC offset changes from -05:00 to -06:00, the instants are correct. How it works: here’s where the calls to `withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap()` and `withLaterOffsetAtOverlap()` come into play. `dt.atZone(zone)` gives us one of the options (`2021-05-08T21:30-05:00[Pacific/Easter]`, so the earlier one, but no sane person remembers that by heart). Since Java knows that there’s an overlap at this time, `withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap()` and `withLaterOffsetAtOverlap()` give us the two different possibilities. Since both convert back to the correct `LocalDateTime`, nothing is filtered out. And since both are different instants, `distinct()` does not filter anything out either. We end up with two `Instant` objects.

### Documetation link

[`ZoneRules.getValidOffsets()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getValidOffsets(java.time.LocalDateTime))

Answer (score 2):

For a given pair of a `LocalDateTime` and a `ZoneId`, all the instants in the list will have the same value and therefore there is no use of creating such a list. I believe what you want is the list of `ZonedDateTime` having the same value for that pair which you can get as follows:

```
// ZonedDateTime for the given pair of LocalDateTime and ZoneId
ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(zone);
ZoneOffset offset = zdt.getOffset();

return ZoneId
        .getAvailableZoneIds()                       // List of timezone names
        .stream()
        .map(tz -> dt.atZone(ZoneId.of(tz)))         // Map the timezone to ZonedDateTime for dt
        .filter(zt -> zt.getOffset().equals(offset)) // Keep only those ZonedDateTimes whose offset is equal to that of zdt
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now(zoneId);
        localToZonedDateTimes(dt, zoneId).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static List<ZonedDateTime> localToZonedDateTimes(LocalDateTime dt, ZoneId zone) {
        // ZonedDateTime for the given pair of LocalDateTime and ZoneId
        ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(zone);
        ZoneOffset offset = zdt.getOffset();

        return ZoneId
                .getAvailableZoneIds()                       // List of timezone names
                .stream()
                .map(tz -> dt.atZone(ZoneId.of(tz)))         // Map the timezone to ZonedDateTime for dt
                .filter(zt -> zt.getOffset().equals(offset)) // Keep only those ZonedDateTimes whose offset is equal to that of zdt
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Panama]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Indiana/Petersburg]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Eirunepe]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Grand_Turk]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[Cuba]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[Etc/GMT+5]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[Pacific/Easter]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Fort_Wayne]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Havana]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Porto_Acre]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[US/Michigan]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Louisville]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Guayaquil]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Indiana/Vevay]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Indiana/Vincennes]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Indianapolis]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Iqaluit]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Kentucky/Louisville]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[EST5EDT]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Nassau]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Jamaica]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Atikokan]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Kentucky/Monticello]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Coral_Harbour]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Cayman]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[Chile/EasterIsland]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Indiana/Indianapolis]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Thunder_Bay]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Indiana/Marengo]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Bogota]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[SystemV/EST5]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[US/Eastern]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[Canada/Eastern]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Port-au-Prince]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Nipigon]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[Brazil/Acre]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[US/East-Indiana]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Cancun]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Lima]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Rio_Branco]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Detroit]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[Jamaica]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Pangnirtung]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Montreal]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Indiana/Winamac]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/New_York]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[America/Toronto]
2021-03-12T16:48:42.368606-05:00[SystemV/EST5EDT]
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: *For a given pair of a `LocalDateTime` and a `ZoneId`, all the instants in the list will have the same value …* This is true for 99.99 % of cases. I believe that the OP meant to ask about the last 0.01 %. When summer time ends or clocks are turned back for other reasons, the same `LocalDateTime` occurs twice in the time zone in question. So yes, to cover all cases we do need a list or other collection capable of holding up to two instants.

Answer (score 1):

For any given pair of `LocalDateTime` and `ZoneId`, there is only one `Instant` - because `Instant` is a moment in UTC offset, the +0:0.

You're probably looking for conversion from `LocalDateTime` to `List<OffsetDateTime>`, which is coded something like this:

```
List<OffsetDateTime> localToOffsets(LocalDateTime ldt, ZoneId zone) {
    ZoneRules rules = zone.getRules();

    return rules.getValidOffsets(ldt).stream()
        .map(ldt::atOffset)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: *For any given pair of `LocalDateTime` and `ZoneId`, there is only one Instant …* This is incorrect. In the cases where there are two valid offset and hence two `OffsetDateTime`s, they also correspond to two different instants. Otherwise an elegant solution.

Comment: Yeah, `getValidOffsets` solves my question. But I agree with @OleV.V. that there can be zero or multiple offsets thus instants. Eg. in zone `Europe/Berlin` when switching from CEST to CET there are two instants which map to the same local time `LocalDateTime.of(2021, 10, 31, 2, 30, 0)`. And on the other hand when switching from CET to CEST no instant for  `LocalDateTime.of(2021, 3, 28, 2, 30, 0)`

Comment: Yeah, because @OleV.V.'s answer returns a list of instants. If I could accept both I would do it.

Comment: @OleV.V. I may be just misunderstanding what's being asked, however, I don't get how any number of offsets built from LDT in one zone can correspond to more than one Epoch-Second (which is what the instant represents). Epoch time scale is monotone, there can't be two of them.

Comment: `Instant`s are monotone alright. `LocalDateTime`s are not always. In the fall back (where summer time ends) clocks are turned backward. For example, say that the second after 02:59:59 is 02:00:00 again. This means that the first time that the clock is 2 is one instant, and at the instant that comes 1 hour later, the local time is again 2. So that `LocalDateTime` does not only correspond to two different `OffsetDateTime`s, those two `OffsetDateTime`s also correspond to two different `Instant`s. If you want to, you may play around with the variant of your code that I put in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Loop all time zones, assigning each as the context for your [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). From each [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object produced you can extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). Some of those `Instant` objects will represent the same moment, where various time zones happened to share the same offset-from-UTC at that date and time.

[image]

In this example code, we start with a particular `LocalDateTime`. That means a date with time-of-day — inherently ambiguous without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. We place our `LocalDateTime` in such a context repeatedly, placing in each and every time zone known to the [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) within our version of Java. The result of placing `LocalDateTime` in a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) is a `ZonedDateTime`. We then extract an `Instant`, effectively adjusting to UTC as `Instant` is a moment as seen in UTC. We put the `Instant` object into a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) as the key. For the value of the map, we have a collection of `ZonedDateTime` objects that report that same instant. So we have a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), a map of key `Instant` to multiple values, a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) of `ZonedDateTime` objects.

```java
LocalDateTime myLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.of( 2021 , Month.MARCH , 23 , 15 , 30 , 0 , 0 );
Set < String > zoneNames = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
NavigableMap < Instant, NavigableSet < ZonedDateTime > > instantToZdts = new TreeMap <>();
for ( String zoneName : zoneNames )
{
    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( zoneName );
    ZonedDateTime zdt = myLocalDateTime.atZone( z );
    Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
    //System.out.println( myLocalDateTime + " in " + z + " is " + zdt + " = " + instant );

    instantToZdts.putIfAbsent( instant , new TreeSet <>() );
    instantToZdts.get( instant ).add( zdt );
}
```

Report the results to console.

```java
System.out.println( "instantToZdts = " + instantToZdts );
System.out.println( "---------------|  " + myLocalDateTime + "  |-----------------------" );
System.out.println( "" ) ;
for ( Instant instant : instantToZdts.keySet() )
{
    Set < ZoneId > zoneIds = instantToZdts.get( instant ).stream().map( zonedDateTime -> zonedDateTime.getZone() ).collect( Collectors.toSet() );
    System.out.println( "Instant: " + instant + " in: " + zoneIds );
    System.out.println( "" );
}
```

When run.

```
---------------|  2021-03-23T15:30  |-----------------------

Instant: 2021-03-23T01:30:00Z in: [Pacific/Apia, Pacific/Kiritimati, Etc/GMT-14]

Instant: 2021-03-23T01:45:00Z in: [Pacific/Chatham, NZ-CHAT]

Instant: 2021-03-23T02:30:00Z in: [Antarctica/McMurdo, Pacific/Tongatapu, Pacific/Enderbury, Pacific/Fakaofo, NZ, Antarctica/South_Pole, Pacific/Auckland, Etc/GMT-13]

Instant: 2021-03-23T03:30:00Z in: [Pacific/Funafuti, Pacific/Norfolk, Etc/GMT-12, Asia/Kamchatka, Pacific/Tarawa, Kwajalein, Pacific/Kwajalein, Asia/Anadyr, Pacific/Majuro, Pacific/Wake, Pacific/Nauru, Pacific/Fiji, Pacific/Wallis]

Instant: 2021-03-23T04:30:00Z in: [Australia/Sydney, Australia/LHI, Pacific/Efate, Asia/Magadan, Antarctica/Casey, Antarctica/Macquarie, Australia/Lord_Howe, Australia/Victoria, Etc/GMT-11, Pacific/Bougainville, Asia/Srednekolymsk, Australia/Tasmania, Australia/Currie, Pacific/Pohnpei, Australia/Melbourne, Pacific/Noumea, Australia/Hobart, Pacific/Guadalcanal, Pacific/Ponape, Australia/ACT, Australia/Canberra, Australia/NSW, Pacific/Kosrae, Asia/Sakhalin]

Instant: 2021-03-23T05:00:00Z in: [Australia/Adelaide, Australia/South, Australia/Broken_Hill, Australia/Yancowinna]

Instant: 2021-03-23T05:30:00Z in: [Pacific/Port_Moresby, Asia/Vladivostok, Pacific/Saipan, Asia/Ust-Nera, Antarctica/DumontDUrville, Etc/GMT-10, Pacific/Truk, Australia/Lindeman, Pacific/Chuuk, Australia/Brisbane, Pacific/Guam, Pacific/Yap, Australia/Queensland]

Instant: 2021-03-23T06:00:00Z in: [Australia/North, Australia/Darwin]

Instant: 2021-03-23T06:30:00Z in: [Asia/Pyongyang, Asia/Tokyo, Asia/Yakutsk, Asia/Jayapura, Asia/Dili, Japan, Asia/Khandyga, Pacific/Palau, Asia/Chita, Etc/GMT-9, Asia/Seoul, ROK]

Instant: 2021-03-23T06:45:00Z in: [Australia/Eucla]

Instant: 2021-03-23T07:30:00Z in: [PRC, Singapore, Hongkong, Asia/Hong_Kong, Asia/Taipei, Asia/Ulan_Bator, Asia/Manila, Asia/Irkutsk, Asia/Ujung_Pandang, Asia/Harbin, Asia/Kuching, Asia/Chongqing, Australia/Perth, Asia/Kuala_Lumpur, Asia/Ulaanbaatar, Asia/Chungking, Asia/Macao, Asia/Shanghai, Asia/Brunei, Asia/Macau, Asia/Choibalsan, Australia/West, Asia/Singapore, Asia/Makassar, Etc/GMT-8]

Instant: 2021-03-23T08:30:00Z in: [Asia/Vientiane, Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh, Asia/Tomsk, Asia/Phnom_Penh, Asia/Jakarta, Asia/Hovd, Asia/Barnaul, Asia/Krasnoyarsk, Asia/Pontianak, Asia/Bangkok, Asia/Saigon, Asia/Novokuznetsk, Asia/Novosibirsk, Indian/Christmas, Antarctica/Davis, Etc/GMT-7]

Instant: 2021-03-23T09:00:00Z in: [Asia/Yangon, Indian/Cocos, Asia/Rangoon]

Instant: 2021-03-23T09:30:00Z in: [Asia/Dacca, Asia/Thimbu, Asia/Omsk, Asia/Qostanay, Asia/Almaty, Asia/Dhaka, Indian/Chagos, Asia/Kashgar, Asia/Urumqi, Antarctica/Vostok, Asia/Bishkek, Asia/Thimphu, Etc/GMT-6]

Instant: 2021-03-23T09:45:00Z in: [Asia/Katmandu, Asia/Kathmandu]

Instant: 2021-03-23T10:00:00Z in: [Asia/Calcutta, Asia/Colombo, Asia/Kolkata]

Instant: 2021-03-23T10:30:00Z in: [Asia/Aqtobe, Asia/Samarkand, Indian/Kerguelen, Asia/Oral, Asia/Ashgabat, Asia/Dushanbe, Asia/Aqtau, Asia/Ashkhabad, Asia/Tashkent, Antarctica/Mawson, Asia/Karachi, Asia/Atyrau, Asia/Yekaterinburg, Etc/GMT-5, Asia/Qyzylorda, Indian/Maldives]

Instant: 2021-03-23T11:00:00Z in: [Asia/Kabul, Asia/Tehran, Iran]

Instant: 2021-03-23T11:30:00Z in: [Indian/Mahe, Indian/Mauritius, Europe/Astrakhan, Indian/Reunion, Asia/Yerevan, Europe/Ulyanovsk, Asia/Dubai, Asia/Muscat, Asia/Tbilisi, Europe/Samara, Europe/Saratov, Europe/Volgograd, Etc/GMT-4, Asia/Baku]

Instant: 2021-03-23T12:30:00Z in: [Asia/Aden, Asia/Qatar, Africa/Nairobi, Antarctica/Syowa, Africa/Juba, Asia/Riyadh, Europe/Moscow, Asia/Bahrain, Africa/Mogadishu, Africa/Dar_es_Salaam, Asia/Baghdad, Asia/Kuwait, Africa/Addis_Ababa, Asia/Istanbul, Africa/Djibouti, Europe/Kirov, Africa/Asmara, Africa/Asmera, Europe/Simferopol, Indian/Antananarivo, Africa/Kampala, Indian/Mayotte, W-SU, Turkey, Europe/Istanbul, Etc/GMT-3, Indian/Comoro, Europe/Minsk]

Instant: 2021-03-23T13:30:00Z in: [Europe/Kiev, Asia/Hebron, Egypt, Europe/Zaporozhye, Asia/Nicosia, Africa/Lusaka, Africa/Gaborone, Africa/Maputo, Europe/Kaliningrad, Libya, Africa/Cairo, Africa/Windhoek, Europe/Mariehamn, Africa/Mbabane, Europe/Vilnius, Asia/Gaza, Europe/Chisinau, Asia/Famagusta, Africa/Maseru, Asia/Amman, Africa/Lubumbashi, Europe/Bucharest, Europe/Uzhgorod, Europe/Helsinki, Asia/Beirut, Africa/Harare, Asia/Tel_Aviv, Africa/Kigali, Europe/Sofia, Europe/Tallinn, Africa/Khartoum, EET, Europe/Tiraspol, Africa/Johannesburg, Europe/Nicosia, Asia/Damascus, Africa/Bujumbura, Asia/Jerusalem, Europe/Athens, Africa/Tripoli, Etc/GMT-2, Israel, Africa/Blantyre, Europe/Riga]

Instant: 2021-03-23T14:30:00Z in: [Europe/Ljubljana, Africa/Libreville, Europe/Berlin, Africa/El_Aaiun, Europe/Oslo, Europe/Stockholm, Europe/Budapest, Europe/Bratislava, Europe/San_Marino, Europe/Zagreb, Europe/Copenhagen, Europe/Malta, Europe/Brussels, Europe/Vienna, Africa/Douala, Europe/Busingen, Europe/Warsaw, CET, Africa/Malabo, Etc/GMT-1, Europe/Podgorica, Europe/Skopje, Europe/Paris, Africa/Ndjamena, Europe/Sarajevo, Europe/Tirane, Africa/Bangui, Europe/Luxembourg, Europe/Belgrade, Arctic/Longyearbyen, MET, Africa/Casablanca, Africa/Lagos, Europe/Rome, Africa/Brazzaville, Africa/Luanda, Africa/Porto-Novo, Atlantic/Jan_Mayen, Africa/Ceuta, Africa/Algiers, Europe/Zurich, Europe/Amsterdam, Poland, Europe/Vatican, Europe/Gibraltar, Africa/Kinshasa, Europe/Madrid, Europe/Vaduz, Africa/Niamey, Europe/Prague, Africa/Tunis, Europe/Andorra, Europe/Monaco]

Instant: 2021-03-23T15:30:00Z in: [UTC, UCT, Portugal, Iceland, Zulu, Africa/Ouagadougou, Europe/Lisbon, Etc/Universal, Europe/London, Atlantic/Faeroe, Africa/Dakar, Etc/GMT, Atlantic/Canary, Africa/Lome, Universal, Africa/Freetown, Africa/Sao_Tome, GMT, Greenwich, Etc/GMT-0, Europe/Jersey, GB-Eire, Africa/Bissau, Europe/Belfast, Africa/Abidjan, Atlantic/Reykjavik, Africa/Monrovia, WET, Atlantic/St_Helena, Etc/Greenwich, Etc/GMT0, Africa/Bamako, Eire, Europe/Guernsey, Africa/Timbuktu, Atlantic/Madeira, GB, Africa/Accra, Africa/Conakry, Atlantic/Faroe, Etc/UTC, Etc/UCT, GMT0, Europe/Dublin, Etc/Zulu, Africa/Nouakchott, Europe/Isle_of_Man, Antarctica/Troll, Etc/GMT+0, Africa/Banjul, America/Danmarkshavn]

Instant: 2021-03-23T16:30:00Z in: [America/Scoresbysund, Atlantic/Cape_Verde, Atlantic/Azores, Etc/GMT+1]

Instant: 2021-03-23T17:30:00Z in: [Atlantic/South_Georgia, Brazil/DeNoronha, Etc/GMT+2, America/Miquelon, America/Noronha]

Instant: 2021-03-23T18:00:00Z in: [America/St_Johns, Canada/Newfoundland]

Instant: 2021-03-23T18:30:00Z in: [America/Argentina/San_Juan, America/Cordoba, America/Sao_Paulo, America/Thule, America/Argentina/Ushuaia, America/Mendoza, America/Moncton, America/Santarem, Canada/Atlantic, America/Asuncion, America/Belem, America/Montevideo, America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia, Atlantic/Bermuda, America/Jujuy, America/Fortaleza, America/Argentina/La_Rioja, Brazil/East, America/Recife, America/Buenos_Aires, Antarctica/Palmer, America/Bahia, America/Goose_Bay, America/Argentina/Jujuy, America/Maceio, America/Argentina/Tucuman, America/Argentina/Cordoba, America/Paramaribo, America/Argentina/Mendoza, America/Nuuk, America/Punta_Arenas, America/Araguaina, America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos, America/Cayenne, Chile/Continental, America/Halifax, America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires, Antarctica/Rothera, America/Catamarca, America/Godthab, America/Argentina/Salta, Etc/GMT+3, America/Argentina/San_Luis, America/Rosario, Atlantic/Stanley, America/Argentina/Catamarca, America/Santiago, America/Glace_Bay]

Instant: 2021-03-23T19:30:00Z in: [America/Indianapolis, America/Cuiaba, America/Iqaluit, America/Curacao, America/Marigot, America/Blanc-Sablon, America/Indiana/Winamac, America/Guyana, America/Martinique, America/Kentucky/Monticello, Brazil/West, America/Boa_Vista, America/Aruba, America/St_Vincent, America/Grenada, America/Puerto_Rico, America/Tortola, America/Porto_Velho, America/Kentucky/Louisville, America/Manaus, America/Port_of_Spain, America/New_York, America/Indiana/Petersburg, America/Indiana/Indianapolis, America/Santo_Domingo, US/Eastern, America/St_Kitts, SystemV/AST4, America/Caracas, America/Dominica, America/Guadeloupe, Canada/Eastern, America/Port-au-Prince, America/St_Barthelemy, America/La_Paz, America/Nipigon, America/Indiana/Vevay, America/Campo_Grande, America/Fort_Wayne, EST5EDT, America/St_Thomas, America/Anguilla, US/East-Indiana, America/Virgin, America/Thunder_Bay, America/Grand_Turk, SystemV/AST4ADT, America/St_Lucia, America/Pangnirtung, America/Montserrat, America/Havana, America/Toronto, America/Indiana/Marengo, US/Michigan, America/Barbados, Cuba, America/Indiana/Vincennes, America/Nassau, America/Kralendijk, America/Antigua, America/Louisville, America/Lower_Princes, America/Montreal, America/Detroit, Etc/GMT+4]

Instant: 2021-03-23T20:30:00Z in: [America/Matamoros, America/Guayaquil, Brazil/Acre, America/North_Dakota/New_Salem, America/Coral_Harbour, America/North_Dakota/Center, America/Winnipeg, America/Indiana/Knox, America/Rankin_Inlet, America/Cancun, America/Cayman, America/Panama, America/North_Dakota/Beulah, CST6CDT, Pacific/Easter, America/Knox_IN, America/Lima, America/Bogota, America/Indiana/Tell_City, America/Menominee, America/Resolute, America/Porto_Acre, US/Central, US/Indiana-Starke, SystemV/EST5, SystemV/EST5EDT, America/Chicago, Chile/EasterIsland, America/Jamaica, Canada/Central, America/Eirunepe, America/Atikokan, America/Rainy_River, America/Rio_Branco, Jamaica, Etc/GMT+5]

Instant: 2021-03-23T21:30:00Z in: [America/Inuvik, America/Yellowknife, America/Regina, America/Boise, America/El_Salvador, America/Costa_Rica, America/Shiprock, America/Denver, America/Guatemala, America/Belize, SystemV/CST6CDT, Mexico/General, America/Swift_Current, America/Bahia_Banderas, America/Managua, Canada/Mountain, America/Cambridge_Bay, Navajo, America/Ojinaga, MST7MDT, America/Monterrey, America/Merida, Pacific/Galapagos, America/Mexico_City, America/Edmonton, US/Mountain, America/Tegucigalpa, Canada/Saskatchewan, Etc/GMT+6, SystemV/CST6]

Instant: 2021-03-23T22:30:00Z in: [America/Tijuana, America/Santa_Isabel, US/Arizona, Canada/Pacific, Canada/Yukon, Mexico/BajaSur, America/Chihuahua, SystemV/MST7MDT, America/Creston, America/Phoenix, America/Dawson_Creek, America/Los_Angeles, America/Whitehorse, America/Ensenada, America/Dawson, America/Mazatlan, PST8PDT, America/Hermosillo, America/Vancouver, SystemV/MST7, Etc/GMT+7, America/Fort_Nelson, US/Pacific, Mexico/BajaNorte]

Instant: 2021-03-23T23:30:00Z in: [America/Anchorage, America/Yakutat, America/Sitka, Etc/GMT+8, America/Metlakatla, Pacific/Pitcairn, SystemV/PST8, SystemV/PST8PDT, America/Juneau, America/Nome, US/Alaska]

Instant: 2021-03-24T00:30:00Z in: [Etc/GMT+9, America/Adak, US/Aleutian, America/Atka, SystemV/YST9, SystemV/YST9YDT, Pacific/Gambier]

Instant: 2021-03-24T01:00:00Z in: [Pacific/Marquesas]

Instant: 2021-03-24T01:30:00Z in: [Etc/GMT+10, Pacific/Honolulu, Pacific/Rarotonga, Pacific/Tahiti, US/Hawaii, Pacific/Johnston, SystemV/HST10]

Instant: 2021-03-24T02:30:00Z in: [Pacific/Pago_Pago, Pacific/Midway, Pacific/Niue, Pacific/Samoa, Etc/GMT+11, US/Samoa]

Instant: 2021-03-24T03:30:00Z in: [Etc/GMT+12]
```

You asked for:

> returns all Instants which are in the given time zone

There is only one `Instant` per time zone per `LocalDateTime`. A date with time-of-day can exist only once within a time zone.

Comment: *There is only one `Instant` per time zone per `LocalDateTime`.* This is true in 99.99 % of cases. I believe the OP meant to ask about the remaining 0.01 %, for example overlaps when summer time (DST) ends and the same local times are repeated.